# How long it takes for a firebase hosting to work?

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I followed the instructions, and deployed a simple web yesterday. At first, it kept showing the default website, saying **" you've deployed successfully..."**, not my web. 
Also, the 'firebase open' command + "Hosting: Deployed Site" leads to a undefined site:' **undefined.firebaseapp.com '**.

But, magically, about an hour later when I open the link from **'firebase console**' again, the web showed up... I am not sure whether 'firebase open' command worked cause I didn't try.

Today, I added some features, and deployed again. In the firebase CLI, it said deployed. But, the link still showed the old version.

I'll catch up an hours later to see whether it works, but even it works, it takes too long.

has anyone had the same experience? what's wrong with my web?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved this issue for my angular 7 app deployment on Firebase hosting:

1. ng build --prod
2. go to dist/myproject and run command Firebase init and...
3. I went to dist/myproject that now contain build files along with Firebase related files. Copy all files except Firebase related files to dist folder in side dist/myproject.
4. there you will get overwrite warning just select overwrite option.
5. after copy process completes, run command Firebase deploy.
6. after completion of process go to shown URL and there you will find your running app.

Comment: thanks for answering, it's been a long time. I got it work, but still thank you for trying to help.